# Error in sql query to fetch data from wamp server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[name]=? and [password]=?' at line 1

```
package com.login.dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
public class LoginDao 
   {
      public boolean check(String uname ,String pass)
   {
    try
        {
        String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";
        String query    = " select * from  login where Name =? and           
        password=? ";

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","root","root");
            PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
            st.setString(1, uname);
            st.setString(2, pass);
            ResultSet rs   = st.executeQuery(query);
            if(rs.next())
                {
                    return  true;
                }
      }
    catch (Exception e)     
      {
        System.out.println("Mistake");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

  return false;


      }
      }
```

Comment: `ResultSet rs   = st.executeQuery(query);` should be `ResultSet rs   = st.executeQuery();`

Comment: Your `getConnection()` needs `:3306/<dbname>`

Comment: @Filburt  thanx buddy that work, can you please explain to me why it happens??

Comment: If you pass the `query` parameter, it will try to execute this unprepared command instead of your PreparedStatement `st`. (see the linked duplicate post).

Comment: @Filburt And technically it is even a bug that MySQL tries to execute the query string. The JDBC specification specifies that calling `executeQuery(String)` on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement` should always throw a `SQLException`